# convert group of repeated columns to one column each using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with repeated group of columns and I want to convert the repeated group of columns to only one column each. 
I know for this kind of problem we can use the function melt in python but only when having repeated columns of only one variable .

I already found a simple solution for my problem , but I don't think it's the best.I put the repeated columns of every variable into a list,then all repeated variables  into bigger list.
Then when iterating the list , I use melt on every variable(list of repeated columns of same group).
Finally I concatenate the new dataframes to only one dataframe.
Here is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd

file_name='file.xlsx'
df_final=pd.DataFrame()

#create lists to hold headers & other variables
HEADERS = []
A = []
B=[]
C=[]

#Read CSV File
df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name='Sheet1')
#create a list of all the columns
columns = list(df)

#split columns list into headers and other variables
for col in columns:
    if col.startswith('A'):
        A.append(col)
    elif  col.startswith('B'):
        B.append(col)
    elif col.startswith('C') :
        C.append(col)
    else:
        HEADERS.append(col)


#For headers take into account only the first 17 variables 
HEADERS=HEADERS[:17]
#group column variables
All_cols=[]
All_cols.append(A)
All_cols.append(B)
All_cols.append(C)

#Create a final DF

for list in All_cols:

    df_x = pd.melt(df,
                  id_vars=HEADERS,
                  value_vars=list,
                  var_name=list[0],
                  value_name=list[0]+'_Val')
    #Concatenate DataFrames 1
    df_final= pd.concat([df_A, df_x],axis=1)

#Delete duplicate columns
df_final= df_final.loc[:, ~df_final.columns.duplicated()]
```

I want to find a better maintenable solution for my problem and I want to have a dataframe for every group of columns (same variable) as a result.
As a beginner in python , I can't find a way of doing this.
I'm joining an image that explains what I want in case I didn't make it clear enough.
[joined image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTKny.png)

Comment: the image is clear, but possible you could add a small example of your data.

Comment: @steven , I will try to approch my columns 's structure. Headers can be an ID of a person ,name ,surname  and his birthdate. B can be a set of vital signs measures along with examination date .C and D are same as B but with different category of measures. every category (B,C or D) is repeated .